# Static tf broadcaster declaration seems to cause nodehandle to be created

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My code is something like this-

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster;
ros::Subscriber fiducial_transform;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "calibrate");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
   ... 
  ....
   ...
   ...
   return 0;
 }
```

I am getting the following error.

```
 You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle
```

Pretty sure it is happening because of declaring the static_broadcaster. Why is this happening? How do I get around this if I have to declare the staticbroadcaster globally?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320492/static-tf-broadcaster-declaration-seems-to-cause-nodehandle-to-be-created./) by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right about the NodeHandle in StaticTransformBroadcaster https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/melodic-devel/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h#L65

You should put the subscriber and the static broadcaster inside a class and construct that after ros::init(), and pass it around as needed instead of the globals if other objects need to use it.

Or if you insist then don't use StaticTransformBroadcaster, instead have a global ros publisher publish `tf2_msgs::TFMessage` as needed.  The broadcaster isn't doing a whole lot as you can see in https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/melodic-devel/tf2_ros/src/static_transform_broadcaster.cpp - it doesn't take much to duplicate the functionality.

Or make static_broadcaster a pointer and again wait until after ros::init to create it.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2019-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-08**:
Or use a smart/bare ptr instead of a plain object.